# NSString convert to NSArray based on text or special Characters

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, delimiter

All,

I have requirement of getting a Array from NSString for Example I have String

NSString* aStr =  @""This is test" Test "Test This"";

Now In Array i need in below format

"This is Test",
Test,
"Test This"

How can we do this